# Undefined control sequence \begin{document} during compiling

Tags: captions

When I try to compile the following code in Texstudio I get  error Undefined control sequence \begin{document}. I think it is related with caption. I tried everything, my texstudio is updated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\title{Mathematics }
\subtitle{Progress report(Mini-presentation) }
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \column{.3\textwidth}
    Stratification frequency is calculated by
    \begin{equation} N=\sqrt{-\frac{g}{\rho_a}\frac{d\rho_a}{dz}} \end{equation} 
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig11}
     \captionof{figure}{Density}
\end{columns}
\section{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

I need help on how to fix this error. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your document example (MWE: Minimal Work Example) works fine. No errors, no warnings! However, your MWE has some issues: you load `caption` twice, `graphics` is loaded by `beamer`, etc ...

Comment: I posted my result,  Still getting the error message. Very strange!

Comment: When I take out the caption packages and the caption itself, it compiles with out error (Ofcourse with out the caption).

Comment: I overlooked, that you not use `frame` in your presentation. See my answer below.

Comment: note the undefined command is not `\begin{document}` unfortunately texstudio scrambles the error message, you need to look in the log file to see the real error message from Tex, which will show which command is undefined.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @Zarko I customized the  frame command in my original presentation like your answer and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes you are right, I saw the errors in my log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer provide own mechanism for image caption (which not work well with `caption` package). Its style you can define with `\beamertemplate{caption}{...}`, `\beamerfont{caption}{...}`.

I would rewrite your MWE as follows:

- used is `frame` environment (it is basic building block of beamer presentations)
- for image is used `figure` environment, but it has -- to my opinion -- sense only if you use numbered captions for images

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
}

\usepackage{mathtools} % it also loads amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{Mathematics }
\subtitle{Progress report(Mini-presentation) }

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \column{.35\textwidth}
    \bigskip
    Stratification frequency is calculated by
    \begin{equation} 
    N=\sqrt{-\frac{g}{\rho_a}\frac{d\rho_a}{dz}} 
    \end{equation}
    \column{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{fig11}
     \caption{Density}
        \end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]